# Change character set for aws rds without restart

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, rds

I am trying to change the character set for AWS RDS mysql instance.

By default, the character sets are as following

```
    +--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                         |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | ascii                                         |
| character_set_connection | ascii                                         |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                        |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                        |
| character_set_results    | ascii                                         |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                        |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                          |
| character_sets_dir       | /rdsdbbin/oscar-5.6.10a.31.59/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I tried with 'set character_set_client=utf8' and it ran with any error, but the character set remains the same.

Also, when I use alter command to change character set and collation of a table, it can't change either the character set or collation.

I am not sure if you can change the character set without rebooting the instance.

Comment: `ascii` seems like an unlikely default; how did that happen?

Comment: I know its late... but take a look at these docs, the's something called "parameter groups" that let you configure your DB from creation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html

Answer (score -1):

I found that this worked for me:

```
alter database [database_name] CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE [database_name].[table_name] CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE [database_name].[table_name] CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```